# IE11 flex child doesn't shrink to give room to other child with non-wrapping content

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

IE11 doesn't shrink a flex child when another child is too small to fit it's (non wrapping) content.

I have gone over the notorious IE flex bugs (https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs) and tried all solutions.

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/adriaanmeuris/ef8Lz7ck/73/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 0px;
  min-width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.center {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 0px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    left<br/> shrinks to 0
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    center<br/> fixed width, always centered (unless right column is too small to fit it's content)
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right<br/> long_content_no_wrap_or_overflow
  </div>
</div>
```

**Expected behaviour (Chrome, FF, Safari, Edge):**

[image: expected behaviour]

**IE11 behaviour:**

[image: IE11 behaviour]

Comment: I haven't tested but it seems IE needs a prefix for flexbox.

Comment: Thanks but I'm specifically targeting IE11 which does not need prefixes for flexbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flex-basis` is set to `0` , remove it or set it to `auto`, else it follows the rule where it can let the element be `0` of `width`'s`basis`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 0px;
  min-width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.center {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    left<br/> shrinks to 0
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    center<br/> fixed width, always centered (unless right column is too small to fit it's content)
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right<br/> long_content_no_wrap_or_overflow
  </div>
</div>
```

... But loosing the second element position from center ...

---

else, **the only workaround i can think of** is `display:table;` (possible alternative to ->`max-content` not supported in IE11)  and `calc()` for `max-width` , so it can't shrink below the content size, but needs a reset for nowdays browser , `initial` can help to avoid regular browsers to go wrong:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 50%), linear-gradient(to top, transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 50%);
  margin-bottom:0.5em;
}

.left {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 0px;
  min-width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.center {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 0px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  /* i work around */
  width: 100%;
  max-width: calc(50vw - 100px);
  display: table;  /* IE11 :  cause max-content is not supported and flex is average */
  /* filter not IE 11 to reset default */
  display: initial;
  width: initial;
  max-width: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    left<br/> shrinks to 0
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    center<br/> fixed width, always centered (unless right column is too small to fit it's content)
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right<br/> long_content_no_wrap_or_overflow
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    left<br/> shrinks to 0
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    center<br/> fixed width, always centered (unless right column is too small to fit it's content)
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right<br/>right<br/>right<br/>right<br/>right<br/>right<br/> long_content_no_wrap_or_overflow
  </div>
</div>
```

the third element doesn't fill the entire width of the row with the table-layout but will stretch its height.

`@supports` can also be another way to filter IE11 here *...( Conditionnal comments where dropped a few version earlier )*

Comment: that solves the overflow problem indeed! but the center column always needs to be centered (unless the right column gets too small to fit it's contents) - that's not the case anymore with your suggested change.

Comment: @AdriaanMeuris , indeed i missed that part, i added a possible CSS work around snippet in the answer , let me know how it behaves for you and if you think it's Worth for IE11 only.

Comment: to clarify : `display:table` is proposed here instead: `min-width:max-content;` ,not supported by IE11, that would have neen handy here.